# java - Which has greater precedence, + or -

Tags: java, operator-keyword, operator-precedence

Considering this expression:

```
x1 = ++x - x++ + --x
```

if the value of x is entered 5

What will be the output of such expression in java, and why?

Comment: `x1` would be `6`

Comment: `+` and `-` have the same precedence, but the `++` prefix/postfix operators have higher precedence than `+` and `-`. See [the table here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html). You also have to keep in mind that expressions are evaluated from left to right.

Answer (score 5):

**There is no greater precedence in + or -**.

Without parentheses they are just executed in the order of apperance, lets consider your example:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 5;
        int x1 = ++x - x++ + --x;
        System.out.println(x1);
    }
}
```

will print 6

There are four operations of pre/post incrementation/decrementation:

- `++x` will increment before evaluation (before using its value in the expression)
- `--x` will decrement before evaluation
- `x++` will increment after evaluation (after using its value in the expression)
- `x--` will decreemnt after evaluation

**Breaking the expression to parts:**

1) "`++x`" the x will be incremented by 1 before using its value in the expression, so for now it is:

```
6 -
```

2) "`- x++`" the x will be incremented by one after using its value in expression, so it is:

```
6 - 6 , but now x=7
```

3) "`+ --x`" the x will be decremented by one, before its value will be used, so it finally translates to:

```
x1 = 6 - 6 + 6;
```

This will be executed as:

```
x1 = 0 + 6;
x1 = 6;
```

Obviously, there is no greater precedence in `+` or `-`, as it is just subtracted and added in the order of apperance.